# Using PHP with Windows

Tags: php, windows-7

I recently inherited a PHP Web Site to maintain. My knowledge is in ASP.Net and HTML. I need help getting started.

I downloaded WAMPServer. It installed ok, but it doesn't run. I try to run it and it just exits. No error message.

I am running Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)?

Comment: @JamWaffles just out of curiosity, is XAMPP better than WAMP? I keep seeing people recommend it over WAMP, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I have used neither, but I read something on the XAMPP site that implied XAMPP is the successor to WAMP.

Comment: Bob, do you by chance have Skype running?  Skype uses the same port as WAMP does and will cause WAMP to crash, or never start.  I spent many hours trying to solve this before I came upon this solution.

Comment: XAMPP is the new WAMPP. Get XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, you probably want to consider XAMPP here http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html.  There is a portable version in there that I highly recommend.  It requires no installation, so it just always seems to run, even when you've had trouble with other setups.

It also has the ability to set things up so they DO run as services, but I'd suggest if you're just getting started, don't clutter up your registry until you get into it a bit and figure out if you really need it **installed**.

Comment: Got these messages current directory c:\xampp; Install(er) directory c:\xampp ERROR: Status check Failure [-2]; this program must run from your XAMPP root directory

Comment: This was running the portable version?  That's what I'd expect from one of the installer versions.  The portable you can literally run from a thumbdrive on virtually any windows PC.